# PDO returns Invalid Argument but it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I have a SQL Query that works PERFECTLY on PhpMyAdmin, but in PHP it returns "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"... Here´s the code:

```
    $materia=$_GET["m"];

    $sqlquery = "select m.cod, m.titulo, m.texto, m.olho, day(m.datahora),     month(m.datahora), year(m.datahora), hour(m.datahora), minute(m.datahora), g.descricao, g.cod from fs_materia as m, fs_grupo as g where (g.cod=m.codlocal and m.cod=$materia)";
    echo $sqlquery.'</br></br>';

    foreach ($banco->query($sqlquery) as $dados) {
```

If you look closely, you'll see that I even ECHOed the SQL Query, so I could copy to PHPMyAdmin... and it works.

I don't understand...

Comment: Show your query. You are wide open for SQL injection. Look into prepared statements and parameter binding for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will fix any quoting issues you may be running into.

Comment: It also helps if you run the query first, and assign the results to a variable, so you can check for query errors.

Comment: What is the value of `$materia`?

Comment: Based on that error message and how your code looks, it seems like the query fails in PHP. You should enable error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: check `var_dump($banco->query($sqlquery));` and see what it's showing

Comment: Did you try to do first $banco->query($sqlquery) and then foreach in two separate lines ?

Comment: No, the query is correct... when I ECHO it and copy to PhpMyAdmin, it works properly there.

Comment: As I see it, query() returns a resource, you need to iterate over the `fetch`-ed rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
...
$sqlquery = "select m.cod, m.titulo, m.texto, m.olho, day(m.datahora), month(m.datahora), year(m.datahora), hour(m.datahora), minute(m.datahora), g.descricao, g.cod from fs_materia as m, fs_grupo as g where (g.cod=m.codlocal and m.cod = :materia)";
$banco->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $banco->prepare($sqlquery);
$sth->execute(array(':materia' => (int)$materia));
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $dados) {
...
```

As alredy was mentioned, you always mus to:

- sanitize/filter variables;
- use the error reporting and log the errors;

Check this link: [Gone Away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: Ok, but... when I ECHo the query, and copy it into PHPMyAdmin, it WORKS...

Comment: select m.cod, m.titulo, m.texto, m.olho, day(m.datahora), month(m.datahora), year(m.datahora), hour(m.datahora), minute(m.datahora), g.descricao, g.cod from fs_materia as m, fs_grupo as g where (g.cod=m.codlocal and m.cod=1093)

Comment: My answer is wrong...
Try to add ```$banco->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);``` before ```foreach```. The problem can be in PDO (configuration);

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/materia.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/materia.php(14): PDO->query('select m.cod, m...') #1 /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/ondex.php(257): include('/home/storage/b...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/materia.php

Comment: Not, it's ok, I wrote it that way and got that error message... and some people proposed that I whould use...

        $results = $banco->query("SET session wait_timeout=28800", FALSE);
        $results = $banco->query("SET session interactive_timeout=28800", FALSE);

I used it, but did not work.

Comment: Now i am trying the new answer... it did not show up immediatly here... lett´s see.

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/materia.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/materia.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/storage/b/6f/ae/espiralinfo/public_html/fabiosalvador/ondex.php(257): include('/home/storage/b...') #2 {main} thrown in

Comment: Try to use the same query with mysqli

Comment: I DID IT!!!!
I deleted a smll portion of code that slowed down the showing proccess of the data... and did! Thank you!!!!!!